# Associative but NOT Commutative Reducing Function Construction with Existing Hash Function(s)

Tags: hash

Is it possible to construct a binary reducing function based on any existing cryptographic hash function satisfying the associative property but not the commutative property? So formally:

Using an existing hashing function
$h: \mathbb{B}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{B}^k $ 
to construct
$R: \mathbb{B}^* \times \mathbb{B}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{B}^{k'}$
so that

- $R(R(a,b),c) = R(a,R(b,c))$, for all $a, b, c \in \mathbb{B}^*$ **(associativity)**
- $R(a,b) \neq R(b,a)$, for some $a, b \in \mathbb{B}^*$ **(non-commutativity)**
- $R$ is as secure as $h$ in sense of

  - pre-image resistance, applied to both arguments, and concatenated
  - second pre-image resistance, applied to both arguments, and concatenated
  - collision resistance, applied to both arguments, and concatenated
  - *additionally*, it should be as hard to find $a, b \in \mathbb{B}^*, a \neq b$ that $R(a,b) = R(b,a)$ as to find $a, b \in \mathbb{B}^*, a \neq b$ that $h(a)=h(b)$, except the case* where $b = R(a,a)$

where:

- $\mathbb{B} = \{0, 1\}$, a bit
- $k, k' \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, the output length of the hash and reducing functions

also, if needed, more than one base hashing function $h$ could be used.

**Background**

The purpose of this construction is to allow the calculation of a collective hash value of an ordered list that can be carried out with arbitrary combinations in any order of the reducing function. So the ultimate goal is to construct a function $H: (\mathbb{B}^*)^* \rightarrow \mathbb{B}^k$ that could be calculated by independent multiple steps.

*the reason to make an exception in the last property is that giving the application, it makes perfect sense that $H(\{a,a,a\})$ gives the same result regardless of how you calculate it (credit goes to poncho; refer to [his answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20967/19959)).

This question is quite similar to [Associative standard cryptographic hash function](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/17935/19959), but not exactly the same. This answer might be useful: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/17936/19959

Comment: Actually, associativity implies more commuting pairs than that; if we designate $a^k = H(\{a,a,a,...,a\})$, then $a^i$, $a^j$ are a commuting pair (for any $a, i, j$)

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that any such function can meet the requirements of associativity, pre-image resistance and the 'hard to find commuting operands' simultaneously.

Here's why: suppose we have a preimage $a$; we first check if $H(a,a)=a$.  If it is, we found a preimage.

If $H(a,a) = b \ne a$, then we have $H(a,b) = H(a,H(a,a)) = H(H(a,a),a) = H(b,a)$ (because of associativity), and hence we found a commuting pair.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Thank you for pointing it out. I'll describe the use case and revise the question tomorrow. It's already too late in my place.